# Como "preg_match" somente números?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Minha tentativa, falhada:**

```
$post_id = preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_POST['post_id']);
```

> Tentei ser um usuário que alterou o id do post para por exemplo: post_id="43223646", Porém, quando os dados são inseridos no mysql, eles são transformados no número 1, como fazer funcionar corretamente?

Comment: Sugiro olhar a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) do `preg_match`. Ele retorna 1 ou 0. Teria que usar o terceiro parâmetro

Comment: como fazer funcionar corretamente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `preg_match` do PHP retorna 1 se a expressão combinou, 0 se não combinou e `false` se ocorreu algum erro.

No seu caso, está retornando 1 porque está combinando.

Mas como você deseja o valor em si, você deve usar o terceiro parâmetro:

> **matches**
>   Se matches for fornecido, ele será preenchido com os resultados da busca.

Faça assim:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_POST['post_id'], $matches);
$post_id = $matches[0];
```

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: obrigado =D, FUNCIONOU PERFEITAMENTE